# Royalty free and free sound effects

Tags: c#, .net, audio, wav

From where I can find royalty free and free of charge sound effects for my C# project? You know, I need an alarm sound in .wav format. There might be some places in internet but I always trust you guys. Please help me.

Comment: and we trust google... Its transitive dependancy!!!

Comment: @M.N.S.: I dnt. and I wont trust ur answer because u r member for 6 days only

Comment: member for 37 days has 54 reputation and member of 6 days have 174 reputation.. dont trust any one on number of days :)

Comment: as if i signing out , bye :) and best of luck for further journey on SO.

Comment: You trust us guys to give you a link to somewhere that's not on stackoverflow to download, which could be potentially dangerous, given that your putting your trust into a stranger. But, I always like to help so here use this... www.google.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Free Sound Project [freesound.org](http://www.freesound.org/) should be what you are looking for. This is my go-to place for sound effects etc